# cannot stop scrolling with overflow: hidden only on ios devices

Tags: ios, css

I'm using popup over whole screen. When popup is opened I set body and html CSS to overflow: hidden and prevent screen from scrolling. In all browsers working fine and on the android devices also, but the problem is on the iOS devices. I cannot stop scrolling on the ios devices.

```
<html style="overflow: hidden;">
<body style="overflow: hidden;">
<div class="popup" style="position: fixed;">
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

I need clean CSS solution for this. I tried already to add position: relative, position: fixed but it's not working.

Any solutions?

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem some days ago and I finally came up with this.

> Well, there is a very simple solution to solve this problem... All you
>   have to do is set that element to have a **relative position**. For
>   instance, if you were to specify for the body to hide the horizontal
>   scrollbars you would want to have the following CSS in your
>   stylesheet:

```
body {
  position:relative;
  overflow:hidden;
}
```

**OR**

Another method is adding jQuery if above doesn't work

we can prevent swiping by using something like so:

```
$('body').bind('touchmove', function(e){e.preventDefault()});
```

And to re-allow swiping again (i.e. when a menu or full screen modal is closed):

```
$('body').unbind('touchmove');
```

Hope this helps you :)

Comment: tried already... unfortunately it's not a solution for my case :/

Comment: how about this? `body{
height: 100%;
overflow: hidden !important;
width: 100%;
position: fixed;}`

Comment: That can work but in my case I have 10 entries and I can scroll to the last one for instance and open modal on that one. In that case screen should stay in that position. With position:fixed it will always go to the top and I don't need that kind of behaviour.

Comment: I think you should add some jQuery. check updated answer

Comment: I know that I tried it's working fine but I'm trying here to find clean CSS solution for this problem. If I cannot than I will do with jQuery that's not a problem I will wait little more :D

Answer (score -1):

Sorry my English. After some days , I found this solution, it worked for me!

```
position: touch-action: none;
-ms-touch-action: none;
```